# RelativeLayout position

Tags: android, layout

I have 3 layouts, in the first I add content programmatically, the secound one I add content programmatically and put it on bottom, the third one I put fragments. The problem is in bottom layout, if I set the height to `40dp` the fragment is displayed. But if I set it to `wrap_content` the fragment is not displayed...

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/acts"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        //android:layout_height="wrap_content" <-id/frame not show
        android:layout_height="40dp" <-id/frame show
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/tabs"
        android:layout_above="@id/acts" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: hm, frame dont show again, it think its position problem, because if i set it to 40dp everything is fine

Comment: Do you use a custom frame layout for Fragments?

Comment: no, just add fragment whit "fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.frame, fragment);"

Comment: do you inflate any layout to the fragment?

Comment: no, i just can`t set the position of the framelayout whit above/acts, if i set acts height to 40dp everything is fine, but i wont the acts to be wrap_content, not 40dp. If its wrap_content my framelayout its positing somewhere over the space and i cant see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fix it, just add the acts layout to bottom of fragment and now its work fine. Tanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Set like this

```
android:layout_above="@+id/frame"
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: its relative layout, there is now weight attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Now i have set background color and set the min Height to show what is happening try this by removing min height of "@+id/acts" layout.Then you will see that the frame is now not in sky :)

**Update**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="50dp"
        android:background="#f00"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="50dp"
        android:background="#0f0"
        android:layout_above="@+id/acts"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tabs" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/acts"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="50dp"
        android:background="#00f"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I have try this, the result is error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'layout_above' with value '@id/acts'). If i set + to id it not show error but the frame is somewhere in the sky :) again

Comment: what do mean by in the sky?  is it still not visible ? or what, share a picture of what is happening?

Comment: top layout is showing, bottom layout is showing frame layout is not visible :(